# Как вернуть вкладки навигации в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

После неосторожных экспериментов с настройками, потерял панель навигации по файлам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Раньше я мог переключаться между открытытми файлами как между вкладками в браузере. Помогите пожалуйста найти где это в настройках включить обратно. Спасибо. Все это под Mac OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Setting` -> `Editor` -> `Editor Tabs` -> `Tab Appearance` -> `Placement` -> `None|Top|Left|Right|Bottom`

У вас наверняка проставлен `None`